# Solving $\displaystyle py+xq+pq=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

To Solve: $\displaystyle py+xq+pq=0$, where $\displaystyle p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

My Attempt:

$\displaystyle p(y+q)=-qx$

$\displaystyle \frac{p}{x}=\frac{-q}{y+q} =a (say)$

$\displaystyle p=ax$

$\displaystyle q=\frac{-ay}{y+1}$

Now, $\displaystyle dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy$

$\displaystyle dz=pdx+qdy$

$\displaystyle dz=axdx-\frac{ay}{y+1}dy$

Integrating this will give a different answer from the given answer, which is

$\displaystyle 2z=ax^2-\frac{a}{1-a}y^2+b$

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: In the second line of your attempt it would appear that you are trying to separate variables. However $p$ and $q$ will in general still be functions of both $x$ and $y$, so the reasoning for separation of variables doesn't apply.

Comment: The book suggests using f(x,p)=F(y,q) as z is absent

Comment: That's fine, but how would you know $f(x,p)=F(y,q)=\text{const.}$?

Comment: I don't .. I am just trying to follow the steps and hoping to learn...

Comment: That's what I mean, though - we don't know that they are equal *and* constant. The reason that sometimes people write $f=F=$const. is because $f$ and $F$ have different, independent variables. If $f(x)=F(y)$ for all x's and y's, then the only way this is possible is if they are both constant (i.e., you could fix some $x$ and try *any* $y$ and the functions would be equal). Now in the case we have here, $p$ may still depend on $y$ and $q$ may still depend on $x$, and this is a complication which makes the above go wrong.

Comment: Thanks .. but how do I solve the problem at hand ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15267/discussion-between-user148176-and-firegarden).

Answer (score 2):

$y\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}+x\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$

$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}+y\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-x\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}+y\right)=-x\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

Let $u=z+\dfrac{y^2}{2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$

$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}+y$

$\therefore\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-x\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}-y\right)$

$\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\dfrac{y}{\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}}-1$

$\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y}=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}}-\dfrac{y\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}}{\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2}$

$\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y}+\dfrac{y\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}}{\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2}=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}}$

Let $v=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\dfrac{y}{v^2}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\dfrac{1}{v}$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{v}$ , letting $v(0)=0$ , we have $v^2=2t$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{x}$ , letting $x(0)=x_0^2$ , we have $x^2=2t+x_0^2=v^2+x_0^2$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{y}{v^2}=\dfrac{y}{2t}$ , we have $t=\dfrac{f(x_0^2)y^2}{2}$ , i.e. $v^2=f(x^2-v^2)y^2$

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$
py + xq + pq = 0,
$$

where

$$
p = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x},\ q = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}.
$$

---

Note that there is a symmetry by exchanging $x$ and $y$, so

$$
z = z\Big( x + y, xy \Big)
$$

---

Note that we can write

$$
py + xq + pq = 0 \Rightarrow \Big( p + x \Big) \Big( q + y \Big) = xy.
$$

So we can write

$$
\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + x \right)
\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} + y \right) = xy,
$$

which can be written as

$$
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\left[ z + \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{2} y^2 + C \right] \right)
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y}
\left[ z + \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{2} y^2 + C \right] \right) = xy.
$$

Let us write

$$
\phi = z + \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{2} y^2 + C,
$$

then we can write

$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = x y.
$$

And let

$$
\phi_x = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x},\ \phi_y = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y},
$$

then we obtain

$$
\frac{\partial \phi_x}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \phi_y}{\partial x},
\ \phi_x \phi_y = xy.
$$

We may try

$$
\phi = \pm x^m y^n,
$$

so we obtain

$$
\phi_x = \pm m x^{m-1} y^n,\ \phi_y = \pm n x^m y^{n-1}.
$$

It is clear that

$$
\frac{\partial \phi_x}{\partial y} = \pm m n x^{m-1} y^{n-1},\ 
\frac{\partial \phi_y}{\partial x} = \pm m n x^{m-1} y^{n-1},
$$

So

$$
\frac{\partial \phi_x}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \phi_y}{\partial x}.
$$

But

$$
\phi_x \phi_y = m n x^{2m-1} y^{2n-1} = x y,
$$

meaning that

$$
m=1,\ n=1.
$$

Therefore we obtain

$$
\pm x y = z + \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{2} y^2 + C,
$$

or

$$
z = \pm x y - \frac{1}{2} x^2 - \frac{1}{2} y^2,
$$

which can be written as

$$
z = - \frac{1}{2} \Big( x \mp y \Big)^2.
$$