# Find general and particular solution for $yp-xq=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am asked to find $2$ things:

1. Find $z$ such that

$$y \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} -x \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$$

2. Find a particular solution if $z$ is specified along a circle
   $$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$ in the $(x,y)-$plane

I tried to start with Lagrange's auxillary equations,
and obtained $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{0}$$

Then I tried to go according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843376/solving-displaystyle-pyxqpq-0) method, but I couldn't understand it.

Can you please show me how to start or give a hint to carry on?

Comment: Are p,q constants? Are you looking for $y$ as functions of $x$? What is $z$?

Comment: Thanks for notification, I changed

Comment: Ok, so your equation is $\triangledown(z)\cdot (y,-x)=0$ .

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I guess $p,q$ are in fact partial derivatives.  We want to find $z$, which is a function of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$$
System of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{-x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{0}$$
Take care that it isn't $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{x}$ but $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{-x}$

A first family of characteristic curves comes from  $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{0}=$finite $\implies \mathrm{d}z=0 \implies z=c_1$.

A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y} = -\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{x}\implies x^2+y^2=c_2$.

The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation is :
$$\Phi(z\:,\:x^2+y^2)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.

Or equivalently on explicit form :
$$z=F(x^2+y^2)$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function.

The arbitrary function has to be determined according to the boundary condition.

In the wording of the question, it is said that the boundary is a curve which equation is $x^2+y^2=r^2$, that is a circle. So the boundary is defined, but the condition is not given :

Citation : 2. Particular solution if $z$ is specified along a circle
$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ in the $(x,y)-$plane.

What exactly is the specification ?

IN ADDITION :

In comments, the condition is specified as : $z(x,1)=e^x$ with $x>0$.

Note that the condition is not along a circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ but is along the straight line $y=1$.

Putting this condition into the general solution leads to :
$$F(x^2+1)=e^x$$
Let : $\quad X=x^2+1 \quad\to\quad x=\sqrt{X-1}$
$$F(X)=e^{\sqrt{X-1}}$$
So, the function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=x^2+y^2$. The particular solution fitting the boundary condition is :
$$z(x,y)=\exp\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}\right)$$

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, it asks whether I can find particular solution or not?

Comment: It asked solution which satisfies z(x,1)=e^x ;  x>0

Comment: @Baimyrza Shamyr : See the addition to my first answer.

Comment: So we used it to find F(X) explicitly. Thanks I understand it now!

Answer (score 0):

From your equation we know that $(y, -x)^T$ is perpendicular to $\nabla z$. This means that it must be in a plane sharing the normal vector of the x,y-plane and that $\nabla z =\alpha (x, y)^T$. Which means the solution is $z = \alpha(x^2 + y^2 - r^2)$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: In the wording of the question, it is not specified that $z=0$ along the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$.